# Facebook Open Graph Actions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a Share Function in my Android App and i'm facing an issue with Open Graph.
I already have my Test User to publish and the SDK and Login integrated in my app.

If i use news.reads action facebook share dialog appears, i click publish but nothing is published to my Wall.
If i use news.publishes everything works ok.

Am i missing something?

Thank you very much in advance.
Maxi

This is my code:

```
        Bitmap image = UtilityFunctions.loadBitmapFromView(mV);
        SharePhoto photo= new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image)
                .setUserGenerated(true).build();


        // Create an object
        ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                .putString("og:type", "article")
                .putString("og:url", ((TextView) mV.findViewById(R.id.linkNews)).getText().toString())
                .putString("og:publisher", "http://www.planetariverplate.com")
                .putString("og:site_name", ((TextView) mV.findViewById(R.id.fuenteNews)).getText().toString())
                .putString("og:title", ((TextView) mV.findViewById(R.id.tituloNews)).getText().toString())
                .putString("og:description", "Compartido desde Planeta River Plate Android App - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fmbaccimobile.planetariverplate.core")
                .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
                .build();


        // Create an action
        ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                .setActionType("news.reads")
                .putObject("article", object)
                .build();

        // Create the content
        ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                .setPreviewPropertyName("article")
                .setAction(action)
                .build();
        ShareDialog.show(activity, content);
```

Comment: Do you see it in your activity log?

Comment: You are a Genious!!! it is there, but why facebook doesn't show it on the user's wall?

Comment: Because Facebook decided what to show on the wall. And it will show stuff that it thinks other people wants to see

Comment: Thank you very much WizKid, you save my day!